# Combining STL(c++11) with WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++11, stl

Im trying to start a new thread using CreateThread and pass the pointee of a shared_pointer as an argument. If i was to use good old ATL, it would call Ccomptr's operator () and increase the ref count and eventually retrieve the pointer.

I'm trying to do the same using STL's shared_ptr, but I'm getting an error where conversion between std::shared_ptr to LPVOID doesn't exist.

```
        std::shared_ptr<X> m_pSettings = std::make_shared(new ....);
        if (nullptr == (m_hBackgroundThread = ::CreateThread(
            nullptr,                // default security attributes
            0,                      // use default stack size  
            ThreadProc,             // thread function name
            m_pSettings,            // argument to thread function 
            0,                      // use default creation flags 
            0)))
        {
            LOG_ERROR(L"Failed to create thread");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading, as `shared_ptr` was never part of the STL (SGI or what was adopted into C++). It's a separate part of the C++ standard library. Also note that you shouldn't be using `new` in `make_shared`. You pass the constructor arguments directly.

Comment: You have to pass a `void*`. Use `new` to allocate some memory. Pass it to `CreateThread`. If `CreateThread` succeeds, then it's the thread's job to destroy it. If `CreateThread` fails, then the thread never runs and the parent has to destroy it.

Comment: Considering you're using C++11, can't you use `std::thread m_backgroundThread; ... m_backgroundThread = std::thread(ThreadProc, X(...));`?

Comment: Yes, using C++11 threads is the better choice, as it will allow the `shared_ptr` to be passed around and maintain the reference count normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer, as you have already been told, is to use `std::thread`:

```
// Hey, look: No magic nullptrs and zeros nobody ever changes to non-defaults anyway!
std::thread t(ThreadProc, m_pSettings);

// Don't forget to
t.detach();
// if you let the std::thread object destruct without first joining it and making sure
// the thread finishes executing
```

Not only `std::thread` solves your problem, it has a multitude of other benefits such as allowing you to pass multiple parameters without fuss, it copies/moves/does-the-right-thing with the arguments you pass, etc. and it doesn't require you to resort to any supposedly clever but actually not hacks. If you use `std::async` instead of `std::thread` you can even get in the caller thread the exception that caused the thread function to unwind if there was one.

The alternative of passing `CreateThread` the address of your `shared_ptr` and then dereferencing it inside the `ThreadProc` **might work, if you're extremely careful** - at the very least you have to make sure the caller's `shared_ptr` doesn't go away until the `ThreadProc` is done with it - but that's just asking for bad things to happen.

Sure, if you had no alternatives that's what you do, but given `std::thread` and friends doing anything else is wrong and a waste of time.

---

Also, your comparison to ATL seems to be founded on a misunderstanding. The difference is not between ATL's smart pointers that are extra-clever and and are able in some magical way to keep the reference count even when giving you the raw pointer (though I am unaware of an `CComPtr::operator()`) while C++ standard library smart pointers are lame and don't do that. The difference is between special object who manage keep their own reference count and manage their own lifetimes given that you declare when you use them (i.e. call `AddRef`) and arbitrary resources.

A smart pointer for COM (be it `CComPtr` or `_com_ptr_t` or any half-baked lame class you fine online) is basically a wrapper around the COM object's innate capability to manage its own lifetime.

You could have just as much added `AddRed`, `Release`, etc. (with the associated semantics, obviously) to your class `X` and wrapped it in a COM smart pointer...

Answer (score -2):

You could pass shared_ptr object by pointer like this: `&m_pSettings`

Then dereference it in your `ThreadProc` :

```
  std::shared_ptr<X> pSettings = *static_cast<std::shared_ptr<X>*>(lpParam);
```

Probably you need to copy your `shared_ptr` first before passing pointer to it into `CreateTrhead` so it'll be in scope while `ThreadProc` running.

Comment: And if the original `shared_ptr` goes out of scope and frees the object before the thread starts running so it can grab the object? It is a race condition.